# [Python]: Python re.search speed optimization for long string lines

Tags: python, regex

I will just ask on how to speed-up re.search on python.
I have a long string line, which is 176861 of length (i.e. alphanumeric characters with some symbols) and I tested this line for an re.search using this function:

```
def getExecTime():
   start_time = time.time()
   re.search(r'.*^string .*=.*', temp)
   stop_time = time.time() - start_time
   print "Execution time is : %s seconds" % stop_time
```

Average result of this is ~414 seconds (around 6 to 7 minutes).
Is there anyway I can reduce this to let say, around ~2 minutes or less?
Based on other's people feedback here, splitting this long line to list of strings will not produce any significant impact in terms of execution time.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Sniffer. Based on the code above, I am just looking if "string <any name> = <any value>" exist.

Comment: OK then look at @Inbar Rose's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.search` already goes character by character, starting your pattern with `.*` will just mean that it will *always* match and every character of the large string can be a candidate... you need to improve your regular expression, or use `re.match` instead of `re.search`.

Also -  You are using `^` in the wrong place I believe, it can either signify the start of a newline, (in which case you need to pass the multiline flag `re.MULTILINE` to the compiler/regex) Or it means "not" when used in character set.

You should change your regex to something like this:

```
r'string [^=]*=.*'
```

This says, look for the word "string" followed by a space, then any number of characters that are not `=` then `=` then anything. Also - You might want to use `+` instead of `*` because `*` can also mean 0 matches, where `+` requires at least 1 character.

But without any more information on your end - it will be hard to tell what exactly is needed.

Comment: Thanks for a very good feedback Inbar Rose. The reason I am starting my pattern with ".*" is because the "string .* = .*" can be on the middle of the long line. It's not necessarily on the beginning of the line. As for your suggestion to use re.match, what's the difference? I mean, doesn't re.match use re.search first? Again, thanks!

Comment: The difference is as I said, `re.search` already takes care of looking anywhere in the string for your desired match, no need to make it work extra hard by saying "look anywhere in the string for *anything* as many times as it wants.. and then the word `string` ... best to just tell the regex to look for the word `string` If you fail to comprehend this, then you should stop all your work and read more about regular expressions before you continue, as this is a very basic concept.

Comment: @jaysonpryde your regex suggested it *was* at the start of the line, can we see your corpus, or examples of exactly what appears?

Comment: @InbarRose I can't use re.match given that the "string .* = .*" is not fixed to occur at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @jaysonpryde I can only help you in so much as you help yourself. I have already explained everything you need to know, for further information you can consult the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). You should at least *try* my proposed solution before you claim that it is not working, or better yet - include some sample data here so that other users and I may check it for you. Also: [search-vs-match](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: @InbarRose Thanks a lot again for the answer and explanations... And for the patience too :)

Comment: @InbarRose  Thank you. I too faced same issue. We were using .* at the start of the RE and  engine is taking too long to match, specially when the match is not found. Your answer saved us.